# Fill Timeseries with founded values or keep NA if no value was found yet

Tags: r, data-cleaning, forecasting

I had a longer TimeSeries and turned it into wider for forecasting purposes, currently timeseries has the following structure :

| Day | Value | Strength1 | Strength2 | Strength3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2 | 1.356 | 3 | NA | NA |
| 2/2 | 1.385 | NA | NA | NA |
| 3/2 | 1.385 | NA | 1.01 | NA |
| 4/2 | 1.4 | NA | NA | 10 |
| 5/2 | 1.6 | NA | NA | NA |
| 6/2 | 1.7 | 4 | NA | NA |
| 7/2 | 1.8 | NA | 1.05 | NA |
| 8/2 | 1.88 | NA | NA | NA |
| 9/2 | 1.98 | NA | NA | 11 |
| 10/2 | 1.8 | NA | NA | NA |

I want a function that :

- given a TimeSeries
- loops through columns  if cell == NA and
  previously only NAs were found in the column , keep NA
- if cell != NA good
- if cell == NA But previously we found not NA values, change to previously found value

This would be result :

| Day | Value | Strength1 | Strength2 | Strength3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2 | 1.356 | 3 | NA | NA |
| 2/2 | 1.385 | 3 | NA | NA |
| 3/2 | 1.385 | 3 | 1.01 | NA |
| 4/2 | 1.4 | 3 | 1.01 | 10 |
| 5/2 | 1.6 | 3 | 1.01 | 10 |
| 6/2 | 1.7 | 4 | 1.01 | 10 |
| 7/2 | 1.8 | 4 | 1.05 | 10 |
| 8/2 | 1.88 | 4 | 1.05 | 10 |
| 9/2 | 1.98 | 4 | 1.05 | 11 |
| 10/2 | 1.8 | 4 | 1.05 | 11 |

I tried this function but it isn't right :

```
filler <- function(df) {
  col <- colnames(df)
  one <- NA
  for (i in col) {
    for (a in i) {
      if(!is.na(a)) {
        one = a
      }
      if(!is.na(one) & is.na(a)) {
        a = one
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tidyr::fill` -

```
filler <- function(data) tidyr::fill(data, dplyr::everything())
filler(df)

#    Day Value Strength1 Strength2 Strength3
#1   1/2 1.356         3        NA        NA
#2   2/2 1.385         3        NA        NA
#3   3/2 1.385         3      1.01        NA
#4   4/2 1.400         3      1.01        10
#5   5/2 1.600         3      1.01        10
#6   6/2 1.700         4      1.01        10
#7   7/2 1.800         4      1.05        10
#8   8/2 1.880         4      1.05        10
#9   9/2 1.980         4      1.05        11
#10 10/2 1.800         4      1.05        11
```